# Reset a column to its default value with GORM

Tags: go-gorm

Is there a way in GORM to reset a column to its default value? MySql provides the `DEFAULT` keyword for this

```sql
UPDATE table SET col = DEFAULT WHERE id = 123
```

There is no mention of updating a column to its default value in the [GORM Update](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html) documentation. Should the [Raw SQL Builder](https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html) be used for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with tags?

My Idea is set `DEFAULT` tag and set value as null and update it. like this:

```golang
type Table struct {
    // other fields
    Number `sql:"DEFAULT:0"`
}

modelTable := Table{} 
// jobs and insert

// get model and prepare then update Number
modelTable.Number = null.IntFromPtr(nil)
modelTable.Update()
```

for create null use [null package](https://github.com/guregu/null).

If this doesnt work then you should use `Raw sql`.